# Use asyncio to do multiple ultimate jobs

Tags: python-asyncio, python-3.7

There are 2 jobs: "wash_clothes"(job1) and "setup_cleaning_robot"(job2), each job takes you 7 and 3 seconds, you have to do it until the end of the world.

This is my code:

```
import asyncio


async def wash_clothes():
    print(f'Start job1')
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print(f'Finish job1, took 3 seconds')


async def setup_cleaning_robot():
    print(f'Start job2')
    await asyncio.sleep(7)
    print(f'Finish job2, took 7 seconds')


async def not_really_asyncio():
    kk = 1
    while True:
        job_list = [wash_clothes(), setup_robot()]
        await asyncio.gather(*job_list)
        kk += 1


async def main():
    await not_really_asyncio()
    # await really_asyncio()    # Still don't know how to do


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

This is the output

```
Start job1
Start job2
Finish job1, took 3 seconds
Finish job2, took 7 seconds
Start job1
Start job2
Finish job1, took 3 seconds
Finish job2, took 7 seconds
...
...
```

But we know that we could put the clothes and then setup the cleaning robot, and take a rest(only few seconds), until one of the job has finished, then do it right now, again and again...

The right output is as following:

```
Start job1
Start job2
Finish job1, took 3 seconds
Start job1
Finish job1, took 3 seconds
Start job1
Finish job2, took 7 seconds
Start job2
Finish job1, took 3 seconds
...
...
```

For now I have a idea to use threading, but it will mess my code.

I want the code to be as concise as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key thing you want that isn't happening in your current code is that, when washing clothes finishes, you *immediately* start washing clothes again even though cleaning robot is still in progress (and will be for another 4 seconds). But this line here prevents that:

```
async def not_really_asyncio():
    kk = 1
    while True:
        job_list = [wash_clothes(), setup_robot()]
        await asyncio.gather(*job_list)   # <--- Waits until *both* finish
        kk += 1
```

`asyncio.gather` waits until all jobs have finished. So even when `wash_clothes` has finished, `gather` will continue just sitting there waiting for `setup_robot` to finish too.

I can think of two ways to fix this.

1. In the `while` loop, use [`asyncio.wait()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) instead of `gather`. This allows you to wait until just one of the tasks has finished, at which point you can immediately start another instance of it.

   This is the most direct way to fix your code from what it currently does. However, it's quite tricky: `asyncio.wait()` is quite fiddly (its parameters are tasks rather than coroutines, and you have to pick apart its return value) and your `while` loop will have to run only those tasks that are not already running.
2. A more lateral idea is to use a separate `while` loop for each of the two tasks. You could put these in separate functions or directly in the `wash_clothes()` and `setup_cleaning_robot()` functions.

Like this:

```
counter = 0

async def keep_washing_clothes():
    while True:
        await wash_clothes()
        global counter
        counter += 1

async def keep_setting_up_cleaning_robot():
    while True:
        await setup_cleaning_robot()
        global counter
        counter += 1

async def really_asyncio():
    job_list = [keep_washing_clothes(), keep_setting_up_cleaning_robot()]
    await asyncio.gather(*job_list)
```

**Bonus chatter** You might find it easier to understand what's going on if you put the time stamp in the `print()` output:

```
# At the start of your script:
from datetime import datetime

# Later on:
print(datetime.utcnow().isoformat(), 'Finish job2, took 7 seconds')
```

Answer (score 1):

Shortest way would be:

```
# ...

async def constantly_wash_clothes():
    while True:
        await wash_clothes()


async def constantly_setup_cleaning_robot():
    while True:
        await setup_cleaning_robot()


async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(
        constantly_wash_clothes(),
        constantly_setup_cleaning_robot()
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

It'll give you output you want.